# Firebase: Joining Firestore Document Results w/ JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wanting to get/read two documents with a `Promise.all` then insert some fields into one response which I got from the other, `.then` set to a final document.

I'm trying to do below and it doesn't error/fail but the data don't get transferred. I'm assuming I must "unpack" the responses, i.e., create a new object and append all the properties then hand that object off for the `.set`?  ...Issue is that these responses can be full of stuff so I was hoping to not have to handle all that.

```
var promises = [getUserInfoFromFirestore(),getOrder(order,"orders")];

Promise.all(promises).then(function (res) {
    //move some user fields to order fields
    res[1].data().soldToEmail = res[0].email;
    finalRef.set(res[1].data()).then(function() {
        deleteOrder(order).then(function() {
            toast("Order Submitted");
        });
    });            
    res[1].data().soldToFirstName = res[0].firstName;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error fetching order:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentSnapshot` objects are immutable.  You will have to remember the results of the first call to `data()`, as it creates a new object each time.  Modify that object instead, and use it in the call to `set()`.

Alternatively, it's easier and more straightforward to use [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) if you just want to modify the contents of a single field in a document.  You don't even have to read the document you want to update.

Comment: Right on. `.update`ing `.then` `.get`ing and finally `.set`ing is the most simple approach. I was overthinking it... Thanks Doug.